# :before element misplaced

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, cross-platform

I don't get why it doesn't work on IE9 and IE10. It works on other browsers but not on those ones. Here is my problem :

[image: s]
<sub>(source: [d.pr](http://d.pr/i/QNwi.jpg))</sub>

```
.briefing h3 {
    margin-bottom: 23px;
    border-bottom: 3px double #9f9c9b;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 22px;
    padding-left: 40px;
}

.briefing h3:before {
    content: url('../img/general-title-decoration-white.svg?1370978950');
    width: 25px;
    display: block;
    top: 2px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

I'm also using this technique on the home page for subtitle decoration. Except that it works:

[image]
<sub>(source: [d.pr](http://d.pr/i/irsT.jpg))</sub>

with this code:

```
.special-title {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #a4a19e;
    line-height: 1.2;
    position: relative;
    padding: 8px 0 8px 38px;
    border-top: 1px solid #e2dbcf;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e2dbcf;
    margin-top: 49px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.special-title:before {
    content: url('../img/general-title-decoration.svg?1369571463');
    position: absolute;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    left: 0;
    top: 10px;
}
```

I've tried to look at the differences but I don't get it.

Also, pseudo elements doesn't appear on my console on IE, so it's a bit hard to test (especially with browserstack).

Any ideas ? I'm stuck there.

[Here is the page where the problem appears](http://aurelieremia.be/work-timburton.html)

[And the page where it doesn't](https://web.archive.org/web/20140516210127/http://aurelieremia.be/)

Thank you very much. :)

Comment: As a side remark, I saw you were looking for an internship, and my company (in Brussels) is often accepting trainees : www.mccann.be ;-)

Comment: @Bartdude A stage offer on stackoverflow ? Not sure it's the best place to show my skills aha but thanks ! I'll check this out :)

Comment: Asking for help isn't showing a weakness, especially if the question is asked well. I would be more concerned about the people pretending they know everything right out from school or unable to show any sign of reflection on their own.

Comment: @Bartdude Well, you're completely right. Many thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not positioning the `:before` element `absolute`?
It should position just fine without it, as long as you don't define `display:block;`

Also, the difference between the two cases is that you set `display:block;` in the first case.

Comment: It's svg with a size set to 100% in its code, so if I don't set display:block, it takes up the whole container. Yep, just noticed that! I'm going to try without. Thanks :)

Comment: Oops, didn't see that it was an SVG. Good luck, let me know the results.

Comment: Well, I tried to remove the display: block and nothing changed. I don't get where the problem come from..

Comment: What happens if you define a height?

Comment: Could you try recreating the scenario via jsfiddle? This way, you could isolate the problem and it would be easier for others to test, since the developer tools in IE don't so well...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to test this, but try using `::before`, which is apparently new in CSS3.